# Writing data to Firebase with NAME as key

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a small react app and i want to write a user to Firebase realtime database

**writeUserData(response.id, response.name)**

```
function writeUserData(id, name) {
        fire.database().ref('usersIOS/' + name).push({
            fbID: id
        }, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                // The write failed...
            } else {
                // Data saved successfully!
            }
        });
    }
```

When i push the user it auto adds a generated key

```
"usersIOS" : {
    "Chris Maher" : {
      "-LjRsCHQPdD94J_DM6vz" : {
        "fbID" : "651085695211111"
      }
    }
  },
```

I want

```
"usersIOS" : {
    "Chris Maher" : {
        "fbID" : "651085695211111"      
    }
  }
```

What do i need to change?

Thanks

Comment: Change push to set

Comment: Ok lets say a user already exists in DB but has other values will it delete them and just have that user with an ID?

Comment: You could do `fire.database().ref('usersIOS/' + name + '/fbID')` to just set that value, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `set` instead of push.

`set` will update the data that is related to a particular doc id but erasing everything that is already there